# how to set default browser on API 19?

Tags: android, android-browser

I use below code, it works on all devices except API 19. In api 19, no default browser set by using this code. Please help me...Thanks in advance

```
 PackageManager packageManager = getActivity().getPackageManager();
        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(mActivity, FakeActivity.class);
        packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
        runDefaultApp();
        packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);


private void runDefaultApp() {
    Intent selector = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    selector.setData(Uri.parse("http://"));
    startActivity(selector);
}
```

Android Manifest FakeActivity:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".FakeActivity"
        android:enabled="false">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: What is the issue on API 19 ?

Comment: on API , no default browser set by using above code. So please give me ideas for android 4.4